# How to know if a project has issues in JIRA

Tags: jira

I am working in a big company and we are having a lot of JIRA projects, I would like to have a dashboard or a way to know if the projects that exist in JIRA are used, e.g if there are any issues in them (I don't need to see the issues just to have a number).
Can I do it without accessing to the database, do I need a plugin, is there a functional way to get the info? :) 
thanks a lot
best regards
Adrien k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with the built-in Two Dimensional Filter Statistics gadget:

- first, search for all issues in your JIRA instance. There may be an easier way to do this, but you can certainly use JQL like `project=ABC or project != ABC`.
- save the search as a filter
- go to a dashboard, add a new Two Dimensional Filter Statistics gadget. Select your newly-saved filter, select "Project" for one axis, and something small in number (like Issue Type) to the other axis. You'll also need to adjust "Number of Results" to exceed the number of issue types in your system.
- save the gadget

Note that the Projects gadget also provides somewhat-similar information with fewer configuration requirements, but as far as I know, it doesn't show the numeric issue totals unless you hover the mouse pointer over the bars.

Comment: hi, good point thanks but if I (as a user) I am not in a role of the project I cannot see it :/

Comment: If you don't have access to the issues, then you can't see them through JIRA, period. (It's a security concern.) if this is the case, then you need to either get access to the projects in JIRA or else get access to the database.

Comment: But that's thing ! I don't want to have access to the issue itself I just want to know if issues exist. :)

Comment: If you don't have any way to request a higher access level and you don't have database access, I am afraid that you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for makes a plugin that can do that - [Structure](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.almworks.jira.structure/server/overview)

[image: Structure with JIRA issues grouped by Project]

That's an example structure containing all issues in available projects, they are then grouped by project, and there's a column showing the number of sub-items (issues) in each group (project).

You can also add a structure to a dashboard/Confluence page.

On a large JIRA instance it be a bit on the expensive side to use it just for that alone though...